# Scattered plot in ng2-charts

Tags: angular, typescript, charts, ng2-charts

I have gone through the documentation of ng2-charts ( https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/ ) but I couldn't find **Scattered Plot** in documentation. Is any other way to achieve Scattered plot chart in ng2-charts ? Any tricks or customization available? Help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [line chart](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/#lineChart) in `ng2-charts` and set the `color` property as follows:

```
<canvas baseChart
   [colors]="chartColors"
   ...>
</canvas>
```

If you define `chartColors` like this:

```
public chartColors = [{
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderColor: 'transparent',
    pointBackgroundColor: '#ff0000',
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBorderColor: '#ff0000'
  }];
```

You will get a transparent background (fill area under the chart) and a transparent line (the points will still be visible - making it appear as a scatter graph). The resulting graph should look something like this:

[image]

Please see [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-chart-example-8xyyxd?file=app/app.component.html) for a demo.